# Imposing custom spacing within citation lists

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, citing, natbib

I want to impose a custom spacing between items on a list of references listed by `\citep` command, akin to what I would do with `\hspace*' in text. One option is to write:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\citep{A,B,C}\hspace*{5cm}\citep{X,Y,Z}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

But I would want to have just one set of parentheses, not two. (That is I want "(A, B, C, [custom space] X, Y, Z)".

Comment: Your question as it stands isn't very clear. Suppose we made a `\mycitep` command, and gave it `\mycitep{A,B}`: what would it do? `\mycitep{A,B,C}`? Without knowing the conditions under which the space should be inserted, it's hard tell what you want. If this is just a one-off use, then  use `\citealp` and put the spacing and parentheses manually.

Comment: I was hoping to be able not only to break citation list at the end of a line (as with `breakcites`), but also to insert custom space between any two items (as one does with `\hspace*`, but without having manually to insert parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a cite command that uses `!` to mark where the space should occur. Only one `!` is allowed in any string of citations.

Syntax is:

```
\spcite[<spacewidth>]{<keylist>!<keylist>}
```

I've set the default spacing to be `3em` but this can be changed in the definition.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@incollection{Chomsky1993,
    Address = {Cambridge, Mass.},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Booktitle = {The View From Building 20},
    Editor = {Kenneth Hale and Samuel Jay Keyser},
    Pages = {1-52},
    Publisher = {MIT Press},
    Title = {A Minimalist Program for Linguistic Theory},
    Year = {1993}}

@book{Chomsky1965,
    Address = {Cambridge Mass.},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {{MIT} Press},
    Title = {Aspects of the Theory of Syntax},
    Year = {1965}}

@book{Chomsky1986,
    Address = {Cambridge Mass.},
    Author = {Noam Chomsky},
    Publisher = {{MIT} Press},
    Title = {Barriers},
    Year = {1986}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\makeatletter
\def\@spcite#1!#2\@nil{\gdef\sp@tmp{#1}\gdef\sp@tmpii{#2}}
\newcommand\spcite[2][3em]{\edef\sp@tmpiii{#2}\expandafter\@spcite\sp@tmpiii\@nil\NAT@open\citealp{\sp@tmp}\NAT@sep\hspace*{#1}\citealp{\sp@tmpii}\NAT@close}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\spcite{Chomsky1965!Chomsky1993,Chomsky1986}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]